# Send simple logs using logstash

Tags: logging, logstash

I'm using logstash to extract logs from a computer and send them to a logstash server. So I have :

- Logstash installed on a remote machine (running as an "agent", I simply add the agent parameter in the command line).
- Logstash installed on my computer (running as a "server").

The configuration files are :

- For the logstash agent :

  ```
  input {
   file {
   path => "D:/mylogs.logs"
   start_position => "beginning"
  }}

  output {
   tcp {
   port => "9900" # logstash port
   host => "10.10.10.1" # remote logstash address
  }}
  ```
- For the logstash "server":

  ```
  input {  
   tcp {
   port => "9900"
   host => "10.10.10.1"
  }}

  output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  }}
  ```

It actually "works". But to see the logs on the server side, I have to stop the logstash agent (it seems that otherwise, logs are not sent). Why this behavior ? I'm new to ELK and I am certainly doing something wrong.

Comment: You might consider running a lighter-weight shipper (like filebeat) on the remote machine.  Have you checked both logstash instance's log files for more information?

Comment: I found a quick fix for this problem. Thank you for the answer, I will use another shipper and I will check filebeat. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tcp plugin of logstash does not append a newline between each event (string), so tcp segment are not sent (until I close the agent program).

On the agent, in the tcp plugin configuration, I add the following property :

```
input {
 file {
 path => "D:/mylogs.logs"
 start_position => "beginning"
}}

output {
 tcp {
 codec => json_lines # Fix the new line problem
 port => "9900" # logstash port
 host => "10.10.10.1" # remote logstash address
}}
```